# VSCode extension - data share between multiple webviews

Tags: svelte, vscode-extensions

I'm creating an VSCode extension that have 2 webviews (for now): sidebar and panel. Both webviews are Svelte apps.

The "main" is the sidebar one. During the interaction with the sidebar, additional webview can be open. The "panel" webview is open as an additional tab in the code editor area.

My workflow at the moment is:

- sidebar Selte component posts message (`vscode.postMessage({command: "XXX", value: "XXX"}`)
- the message is received in the sidebar provider
- the sidebar provided creates new panel view

During the creation of the panel view some data is passed from the sidebar (`value: "XXX"`).
As long as the passed data is simple then there is no issue.

My problem is that I have to share connection object which is more complex and contains methods as well. If I try and send the complex object as it is im getting the following error:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'MessagePort'
```

As far as ive understood this is because the complex structure of the data. I've tried to `JSON.stringify()` the data before sending it but then im getting:

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

So the questions are ... is there another way to share data between webviews (which are part of the same extension)? Is there something like extension context or store where data can be set and accessed from all extension components? Or the only way is to post messages between the providers.

P.S. The shared data should not persist

### EDIT

I'll leave the question open if someone wants to dig into this but I've realized that my approach is probably not very good.

At the moment the siedebar webview is establishing the connections and tries to pass it to other webviews. What I think is better is all the communication with the backend to be implemented inside the extension code itself and for the webviews to only request data from there (by simple `postMessage` instead of actually communicating with the backend themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The views are all in iframes which isolates them quite strictly; i doubt that there is a way for them to communicate.

I would recommend reducing what you send to simple data (commands with arguments or data requests). Libraries like [`devalue`](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/devalue) can at least help with things like cyclical references.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ive just updated my question with more details how to approach this. In general i think ive started it wrong and indeed its not natural to implement the backend communication into the webviews

Comment: Yes, you should limit the messages as much as possible. It can be just events/commands and requests for data.